# difference between environment variables and System properties

Tags: java

iam using the below link to understand environment variables and system properties.

*https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html*

The link says environment variables are set by OS and passed to applications. 
When i fetch environment variables using `System.getenv()` it shows me lot of properties which i never set.
So it must be OS (im using macOS) which had set these properties. 
Some of the properties in `System.getenv()` are **MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS**, **JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_1420**, **JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_1430**.

My question is why would OS would like to set the java specific properties in environment variables? Ideally these should be set by JVM (in `System.properties()`).

P.S.: From whatever i have read on net i understand that environment variables are set by OS and System.properties() are set by JVM

Also if someone can point me to a good link on environment variable and System.properties it will be very helpful. Iam very confused between the two.

Comment: Environment variables are OS level variables, they do't necessarily need to be set by the OS. You can set them yourself as well, and sometimes scripts do the same (like the maven script which will export/set variables as well). Java system properties are those which are passed to your progam with `-D` on the command line (or programmatically through `System.setProperty`.

Comment: Environment variables are used on the OS to configure stuff. These variables can be used by any program. They can be set system-wide or by specific users. Different programs are interested in different environment variables. Java just happens to be one of the programs running on the OS. So `System.getenv()` is Java's way of giving your program access to environment variables (because your program may be interested in one of them). Nothing special. I'm sure you know all about Java's own system properties. That's a Java-specific way of configuring stuff throughout the JVM instance.

Comment: @ernest_k 
you mean to say thet the values which i get by System.getenv() are sent to other process also. for example: firefox, chrome etc. the properties i mentioned in the questions are also passed to other applications. is it possible?

Comment: @tin_tin Yes. Not always, though (if you understand how variables work, you'll see that they can be bound to a shell session such that only programs launched in that session will "see" those variables). This may be OS-specific. So if you have OS-wide variables, all processes have access to them. If you have user-level variables, all processes run by that user have access to them. It's more like "programs *pull* variables" rather than "the OS *pushes* variables to programs"

Comment: @ernest_k It is more like the process (program) that starts another process (program) *pushes* environment variables to the new process. Every process has its own copy of environment variables, so modifying the environment variables of a process will not affect the environment variables of other processes started by that process.

Comment: @Andreas I've never seen things like that (yep, never tested variables where I launch the process). The relevance of pull/push is minor here, though; but I need to check how variables reach running programs. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables is an OS concept, and are passed by the program that starts your Java program.

That is usually the OS, e.g. double-click in an explorer window or running command in a command prompt, so you get the OS-managed list of environment variables.

If another program starts your Java program<sup>1</sup>, e.g. an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, ...) or a build tool (Maven, Groovy, ...), it can modify the list of environment variables, usually by adding more. E.g. the environment variable named `MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS` would tend to indicate that you might be running your program with Maven.

In a running Java program, the list of environment variables cannot be modified.

---

System properties is a Java concept. The JVM will automatically assign a lot of 
system properties on startup.

You can add/override the values on startup by using the `-D` command-line argument.

In a running Java program, the list of system properties can be modified by the program itself, though that is generally a bad idea.

---

<sup>*1) For reference, if a Java program wants to start another Java program, it will generally use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to set that up. The environment variables of the new Java process will by default be the same as the current Java program, but can be modified for the new Java program by calling the [`environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--) method of the builder.*</sup>

Comment: i was looking for an answer like yours. Answer by you and ernest_k cleared lot of doubts. Feels like nirvana